# Image overlays fixed button

Tags: html, css

I have a sticky button on the bottom right of my page, but my images overlay my button. it only happens with the first load of pictures, i have 4 others on the bottom of the page and they work perfectly fine. anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

```
<a href="https://wa.me/+31653557446" style="position:fixed; display:block; width:60px; height:60px; bottom:40px; right:40px; background-color:#25d366; color:#fff; border-radius:50px; text-align:center; font-size:30px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;" class="float" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
</a>
```

Code of pictures that overlay the button.

```
<div class="w3-row-padding">
      <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
        <div class="w3-display-container">
          <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">Before</div>
          <img src="img/HuisBefore.jpg" alt="Before" style="width:99%" class="w3-round">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
        <div class="w3-display-container">
          <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">After</div>
          <img src="img/HuisAfter.jpg" alt="After" style="width:99%" class="w3-round">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
        <div class="w3-display-container">
          <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">Before</div>
          <img src="img/VoordeurBefore.jpg" alt="Before" style="width:99%" class="w3-round">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
        <div class="w3-display-container">
          <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">After</div>
          <img src="img/VoordeurAfter.jpg" alt="After" style="width:99%" class="w3-round">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Code of pictures that DONT overlay the button (which is good)

```
<div class="w3-row-padding" id="reviews">
  <div class="w3-container w3-padding-32"></div>
    <h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-16">Reviews</h3>
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
    <img src="img/Review1.jpg" style="width:100%" class="w3-round">
    <h3>Mirella Bloemberg</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">Assendelft</p>
    <p>Er werd goed geluisterd naar onze wensen, mee gedacht en advies gegeven! Ze zijn perfectionistisch en hebben oog voor detail. Zeer tevreden met het eindresultaat, wij zijn de eerst komende jaren weer klaar!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
    <img src="/img/team1.jpg" style="width:100%" class="w3-round">
    <h3>Voornaam Achternaam</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">Woonplaats</p>
    <p>Phasellus eget enim eu lectus faucibus vestibulum. Suspendisse sodales pellentesque elementum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
    <img src="/img/team3.jpg" style="width:100%" class="w3-round">
    <h3>Voornaam Achternaam</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">Woonplaats</p>
    <p>Phasellus eget enim eu lectus faucibus vestibulum. Suspendisse sodales pellentesque elementum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
    <img src="img/Review2.jpg" style="width:100%" class="w3-round">
    <h3>Carolina Deelen</h3>
    <p class="w3-opacity">Amsterdam Noord</p>
    <p>Wat een plezier als Rody aan het werk is in je huis. Heel zorgvuldig in alles wat hij doet, past hij naadloos in terwijl het leven en werken in huis gewoon door gaat. Bij ons werden de binnenkanten van de kozijnen geschilderd en toen er opeens een behoorlijke beschadiging bleek, heeft hij vakkundig geadviseerd en het prachtig opgelost. Het totaal levert professioneel, mooi, schoon en strak schilderwerk. Ik ben er heel blij mee en ga zeker nog meer laten schilderen! </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor, you can create one or more [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Can't know for sure since you didn't include your css but you can try to add `z-index: 999` to the button